# Are all gases equal in their ability to carry with them lower volatility matter at a given temperature?

Tags: aqueous-solution, water, solubility, distillation, gas-phase-chemistry

As we all know water is a great solvent in it's liquid form relative to other substances. I wonder however how it performs as a gas relative to other stuff.

Does anyone know how well steam carries compounds with it compared to other gases at the same temperature and pressure?

Comment: Arguably, no gas is a good solvent.

Comment: Or they are all perfect, depending on what on Earth you mean!

Comment: *Supercritical water* dissolves for a lot of things you usually think are perfectly insoluble, like many inorganic solids.

Comment: Are all gases equal in their ability to carry with them lower volatility matter at a given temperature?

Comment: @Hans, think about gas chromatography, if you are familiar with it. Does the retention time change if you change gases, say, nitrogen to helium or hydrogen? No, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

It *depends* on how a solvent is defined. Regardless of semantics, supercritical steam 217.75 atm, 373.946 °C is a very good solvent. It will dissolve fats, hydrocarbons or plastics. It also becomes very corrosive to metals.

[image]

Comment: Thing is, you're talking about liquid-like supercritical H2O, which I wouldn't call steam.

Comment: Supercritical "fluid" is neither a typical gas nor liquid. It does not matter whether you accept the term supercritical steam or not, I would rather worry if the scientific community accepts it or not. "Supercritical steam" brings up at least 9700 results in Google Scholar.

Comment: Perhaps read my comment again and check out on supercritical fluids, before responding...

Comment: Mithoron, Please bring some positivity in your tone. Instead of criticizing answers mainly on semantics or trivial issues and downvoting almost every other question, why don't you write a separate answer if you have a better explanation. Perhaps in a better way, instead of cursing the darkness, why not light a lamp? SE Chem is a volunteering Q&A site. Make this a productive place. BTW, what is your area of specialization?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22185/does-the-density-of-a-liquid-and-gas-phase-of-a-substancenitrogen-or-water-con https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/122239/is-oxygen-above-the-critical-point-always-supercritical-fluid-would-it-still-ap